# Is there a database of all the technical terms used in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Watching Star Trek I've encountered several terms I'm not familiar with. For example, they use the term "neurtinos" a lot and "dilithum."?

Some of these sound obviously fake but then there are things like "synaptic transceiver" which sound like a real thing.

Is there a database of words like this?

Comment: Neutrinos and [dilithium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Star_Trek_terminology).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a joke, I think.

Comment: Edited to make it seem more serious.

Comment: "New Tree Nose"? Are you for real? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Memory alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Portal%3aMain) is considered to be the "go-to" reference guide for Star Trek technical gobbledegook. Please note that while many of the words you hear on the show are real, there's also a fair amount of pure [treknobabble](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Technobabble) scattered in there as well.

- You can usually see the correct spellings if you locate a [script guide](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/) or read the [online transcripts](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/episodes.htm) for various episodes.
- Offline, you may wish to consider investing a couple of pounds getting the "Star Trek Encyclopedia".
- Since English may not be your primary language, you might also want to use the ["voice search](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/voicesearch/index-chrome.html)" facility on google. Saying the words out loud, Google can often work out what you mean, even if you yourself don't know the correct spellings.

For the record, a [neutrino](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Neutrino) is described as :

> Neutrinos are elementary particles which belong to the lepton family
>   of particles. They have very small masses, and hence travel at close
>   to the speed of light. Although they interact very rarely, a
>   starship's sensor array contains instruments capable of detecting
>   them.

---

and [dilithium](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dilithium) is described as :

> Dilithium, also known as radan, was an [fictional] element, a member of the
>   hypersonic series, mostly occurring as crystalline mineral. It was
>   used to control the power of the warp drive systems of many starships
>   by regulating the matter/antimatter reaction in a ship's warp core

Comment: This doesn't make clear that neutrinos do exist (you'll find a much more useful definition in Wikipedia) but dilithium doesn't, and couldn't - it can't be an element that occurs in nature, because all those elements are known, and there are no gaps in the periodic table for any more.  There are a number of transuranic elements at the end of the periodic table, but these have all been synthesised, in extremely small quantities, and are highly unstable, with half-lives measured in microseconds.

Comment: @PeterClose - it is possible however that even higher elements may be much more stable, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability